# How do I add a branch master to git config. I need a command line solution

Tags: macos, git, terminal

I want to add these lines to git config. I need a command line solution.

```
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git config branch.master.remote origin` to set the value `remote`.

`git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master` to set the value `merge`.

`git config branch.master.remote` to read values.

The `git config` could be used to edit any value. The rules are simple. I explain by example. The `git config a.b.c.d.e.f 42` produces the config section like this:

```
[a "b.c.d.e"]
    f = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Before git version **1.7.0** you'd need to do this:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge  refs/head/master
```

As of git 1.7.0 and later you can do this:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

They do the exact same thing.